# Why can't JavaScript send commands to the OS level?

Tags: javascript

If HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are processed by the user's computer, why can't JavaScript send commands to the OS level? I know if this happened, hackers could exploit a lot of computers but what prevents it from happening?

Comment: theres a sandbox.

Comment: JS communicates with the browser (or at least a component of the browser). If the browser chooses not to allow the script to do something, it has the ability.

Comment: There is no API in browsers that exposes sending commands to the OS level. This is by design, to prevent web hacking of users computer as you say. By contrast WIndows Script Host does expose a shell command, and can run script files by double clicking (even extensions are hidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : its the **browser**, you see browser is like any other program on your computer given enough permissions it can do whatever it wants to through system calls.It can access your hard drive (and not just simple filesystem i mean block/sector level access) reading/deleting whatever it wishes it can even read/edit your MBR!.Other fun stuff like ejecting CD tray/ put os to shutdown or sleep/ formatting your drives xD / infinite nag screens/ disabling network adapters/ and other crazy cool stuff you can imagine all can be done if browser makers wish to expose those functionality through javascript, for eg. if microsoft in some distant future were to expose some system API through `system` object much analogous to the  `window` object in current javascript spec. .You write a script like this one `<script>system.ejectDrive['cd']</script>` , browser may translate in into actuall winapi call `mciSendCommand(mPar.wDeviceID, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_OPEN, 0);` and bingo ! its cool but what if a hacked ebay server sent you code for wiping your D:\ drive clean?.Now you can imagine why browser makers take security so seriously.You might wonder why i'm so obsessed with disk drive ejection xD, actually i chose this example due to its physical nature . A random bit changed in his computer's memory may mean nothing to an average user unless it has some sort of " physical effect " even though that effect might be dependent on that bit somehow.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can have access to your computer in some cases:
https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/06/20/ransomware-thats-100-pure-javascript-no-download-required/

Some ransomwares have their js files as e-mail attachments and tempt users to open it *locally*.

It is not about JavaScript, it is about the software that runs the script, and how the software interprets it.

With js in browser, it can only do what the browser allows it to.
With Node.JS, you can write "JavaScript" to start your own server.
When run locally in Windows via a double click, it can be very dangerous.